# Are all faithful, irreducible representations over $\mathbb{C}^n$ of a given finite group equivalent?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

Suppose I have a finite group $G$ of order $r$, and two finite-dimensional irreducible representations $D^{(1)}$ and $D^{(2)}$ both over $\mathbb{C}^n$. If these two representations are faithful, then is it true that there exists an equivariant map (or intertwining map) $S\in GL(\mathbb{C}^n)$ between the two representations?

$$S\circ D^{(1)}(g) = D^{(2)}(g)\circ S$$

Does the answer change if the two representations are instead over $\mathbb{R}^n$, but still allow the map $S$ to be complex?

$$ D^{(1)}(g), D^{(2)}(g) : \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$$

$$S:\mathbb{C}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{C}^n$$

Comment: I have edited my answer to include answering your edited extra question.

Answer (score 5):

This is not true, for example faithful $1$-dimensional representations of the cyclic group of order $p$.

But it fails in a big way: let
$$m(G)=\max_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \{\text{number of inequivalent irreducible representations of $G$ of degree $n$}\}.$$
There exists a function $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ such that if $m(G)=n$ then $|G|\leq f(n)$, i.e., $|G|$ is bounded in terms of $m(G)$.

In the special case of symmetric groups, all of these (not of degree $1$) are faithful, and defined over $\mathbb{Q}$.

As two representations are equivalent over $\mathbb{C}$ if and only if they have the same character, the field over which the change of basis matrix (the intertwiner) is taken is irrevelant.

Comment: This is very interesting. If I understand the example of 1-dimensional representations of cyclic groups correctly the various inequivalent representations *are* equivalent in a different sense, namely that the images $D^{(1)}(G)$ and  $D^{(2)}(G)$ are equal. In other words: there is only one subgroup of $\mathbb{C}^n$ isomorphic to $G$ in this case. Do you know if somehing similar holds for more general groups, e.g. all subgroups of $GL(2, \mathbb{C})$ isomorphic to $A_5$ are conjugate to eachother?

Comment: The next theorem you therefore want is when two irreducible representations yield the same subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$. This is true for $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$ if and only if there exists an automorphism $\phi\in\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ such that $\rho_1\circ \phi=\rho_2$.

Comment: Yes, that equivalence is pretty clear. But do you know for which groups and which $n$ we have that *all* irreducible $n$-dimensional representations are related in this way?

Comment: So you want to know for which finite groups $G$ all faithful irreducible representations of the same dimension are $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$-equivalent? That's surely a hopeless question in general. Notice that the example of $S_n$ that I gave has the property that $\mathrm{Aut}(S_n)=S_n$ (unless $n=2,6$), so this example holds with your stronger statement.)

Comment: For example, your statement is true for all abelian groups, the dihedral and quaternion groups of order $8$, the group $C_p\rtimes C_{p-1}$, the normalizer of a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $S_p$, $A_5$ but not $S_5$, and $A_6$, but not $A_7$.

Comment: Ha, this is great!

Comment: "In the special case of symmetric groups, all of these (not of degree 1) are faithful," ...for $n \geq 5$. For instance, there is a two-dimensional irreducible representation of $S_4$ that is not faithful.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the representations $h_1$, $h_2$ of $\mathbb{Z}/2$ defined on $\mathbb{C}^2$ by $h(1)(x,y)=(-x,y)$ and $h_2(1)(x,y)=(-x,-y)$ there are faithfull but not equivalent because the fixed of the second is $1$-dimensional and the fixed set of the first is $\{0\}$.

Consider the representation of $\mathbb{Z}/4$ defined by $h_1(1)(z)=-z$ and $h_2(1)(z)=e^{i{2\pi\over 4}}z$.

Comment: Oh sorry I also meant irreducible.